# POST request with chunked body - response HTTP/1.0 411

Tags: apache, http, http-post, transfer-encoding, http-status-code-411

I have an Apache2 server with a .php file that echo the request body to the screen.

I'm trying to send a POST request to the file with chunked body and the response is HTTP/1.0 411.

How can I configure the Apache to response with HTTP/1.1 and understand my request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that the PHP module is enabled in your httpd.conf file?